# Is making a class like "CustomEvent", that can carry parameters, is in accordance with rules of OOP

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, oop

My friend recently said, that you should find some way without "CustomEvent" if you wanna follow OOPs strictly. Is this true ? Is this the reason, that such class is not provided by Adobe natively ? In many of my projects, i find it impossible to  communicate without being able to send information via parameters. Is using "CustomEvent" like thing, a breach into OOP rules.

thanks
V.

Comment: "CustomEvent" and OOP have nothing to do with each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @James Tomasino: Using custom events is not a breach of OOP principles - in fact, it is a useful thing in most cases.

But.

If you want to use your events to communicate between separate SWFs, e.g. if you have one clip that loads another clip, and then want to send an event to notify the loader about something that happened in the "loadee", you would have to include your custom event class in both, thus requiring you to make sure you always keep your dependencies synched.
In order to keep files loosely coupled, you'll want to stick to `flash.events.Event`, or any other native event class, for all communication that is supposed to "cross over" between SWFs.

Answer (score 3):

There are hundreds of "CustomEvents" built into flash natively and it is totally within the bounds of OO to make your own. Rather than define one generic event with a data property, though, make your events specific and their properties as well.